# Make a pinpointed location move on the map while walking without using GPS in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm developing an In-door positioning using Wi-Fi trilateration method. I currently able to get my position on the map but right now I wants to make the point move towards the direction I walking and keep update on the map without using GPS. Is there any motion detection sensor to do this function?

Comment: `LocationListener.onLocationChanged()` should work the same between WiFi and high-accuracy GPS

Answer (score 0):

wifi will not give you a high enough accuracy to do this it will give you a general area.